# I want to parameterize TABLE_TO_BE_DELETED table in below stored PROC

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

but not by taking argument variable, I have a table which hold all the TABLE information from there i want to take one by one table names finish deleting fetch another table name

BEGIN
 DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
 loop1: WHILE SQLSTATE = '00000' DO
  delete from ABC.TABLE_TO_BE_DELETED where ID in 
  (select ID from ABC.ID_DIM ) FETCH FIRST 2000000  ROWS ONLY WITh UR;

IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN -- not found
   LEAVE loop1;
  END IF;
  COMMIT;
 END WHILE;
END@

Comment: Please show your expected result. I'm not sure I understand the question (where is the question?) In general, make it easy on the folks who want to suggest a solution. Show what you want; what you've done; what fails.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to parameterize table names in Db2.  I.e. use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in your loop

Comment: Per IBM:- You cannot use the ISOLATION (UR) option for the following types of statements:  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE.  You have to remove it or all you'll get is an error.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is fetch the results of your table of tables in a cursor, and then loop them

Something in the lines of:

```
DECLARE Tables_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM table_of_tables

OPEN Tables_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Tables_cursor INTO @table_name

DELETE FROM @table_name where ID in
(select ID from ABC.ID_DIM ) FETCH FIRST 2000000 ROWS ONLY WITh UR;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    FETCH NEXT FROM Tables_cursor INTO @table_name
END
```

I have never used, but I think it would be something like:

```
   EXEC SQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
     SELECT tablename  FROM table_of_tables

    EXEC SQL OPEN C1;
    DO WHILE (SQLCODE = 0);
     EXEC SQL FETCH C1 INTO :TABLE_NAME
     DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME as curentTable where ID in
     (select ID from ABC.ID_DIM ) FETCH FIRST 2000000 ROWS ONLY WITh UR;
    END;
    EXEC SQL CLOSE C1;
```

Comment: I think the OP is using Db2, not SQL Server.

Comment: Yes i need this same logic in DB2

Comment: If that's what you needed, please mark the answer as a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

For massive delete rows in chunks for multiple tables from a dynamic list, if I got you goal correctly.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';

  FOR V AS C1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
   SELECT 'DELETE FROM (SELECT 1 FROM ' || TABNAME || ' T WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC.ID_DIM D WHERE D.ID = T.ID) FETCH FIRST 2000000 ROWS ONLY WITH UR)' AS STMT 
   FROM TABLE_WITH_COLUMN_TABNAME
  DO
    L1: LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V.STMT;
      IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
      COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
  END FOR;
END@
```